# Push notification not showing customised notification

Tags: ios, swift

Hey I am trying to get push notifications from firebase and customise them as needed but it always gives me default push notification even when i have set notification category in application launch options. So please tell me how can i show customised push notification() in this case. Here is my app delegate file:-

```
//
//  AppDelegate.swift
//  FireBasePostNotification
//
//  Created by Rajat Bhatt on 2/16/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Rajat Bhatttixdo. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import UserNotifications

import Firebase
import FirebaseInstanceID
import FirebaseMessaging

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message_id"

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        if let lo = launchOptions {
            let notification_details: NSDictionary = lo[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] as! NSDictionary
            debugPrint(notification_details)
            self.scheduleNotification(userInfo: notification_details as! [AnyHashable : Any])
        }
        // Register for remote notifications. This shows a permission dialog on first run, to
        // show the dialog at a more appropriate time move this registration accordingly.
        // [START register_for_notifications]
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            configureUserNotification()
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })

            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
            // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
            FIRMessaging.messaging().remoteMessageDelegate = self
        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        // [END register_for_notifications]
        FIRApp.configure()

        // [START add_token_refresh_observer]
        // Add observer for InstanceID token refresh callback.
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(self.tokenRefreshNotification),
                                               name: .firInstanceIDTokenRefresh,
                                               object: nil)
        // [END add_token_refresh_observer]
        return true
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        print("APNs token retrieved: \(deviceToken)")
        let deviceTokenString = deviceToken.reduce("", {$0 + String(format: "%02X", $1)})
        print("Device token string: \(deviceTokenString)")
        FIRMessaging.messaging().subscribe(toTopic: "/topics/post")
        print("Subscribed to news topic")
        // With swizzling disabled you must set the APNs token here.
        FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.sandbox)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        print("Unable to register for remote notifications: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    // [START receive_message]
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {

        // Let FCM know about the message for analytics etc.
        FIRMessaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
        // handle your message

        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
        // TODO: Handle data of notification
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)
        //scheduleNotification(userInfo: userInfo)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        print("didReceiveRemoteNotification")
        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
        // TODO: Handle data of notification
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)
        //scheduleNotification(userInfo: userInfo)

        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        FIRMessaging.messaging().disconnect()
        print("Disconnected from FCM.")
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        connectToFcm()
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }

    func tokenRefreshNotification(_ notification: Notification) {
        if let refreshedToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token() {
            print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")
        }

        // Connect to FCM since connection may have failed when attempted before having a token.
        connectToFcm()
    }

    private func configureUserNotification() {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            let action = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "dismiss", title: "Cancel", options: [])
            let category = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "myNotificationCategory", actions: [action], intentIdentifiers: [], options: [])
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories([category])
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }

    }

    func scheduleNotification(userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) {
        //        let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        //        let components = calendar.dateComponents(in: .current, from: date)
        //        let newComponents = DateComponents(calendar: calendar, timeZone: .current, month: components.month, day: components.day, hour: components.hour, minute: components.minute)

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 02, repeats: false)
            let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
            content.categoryIdentifier = "myNotificationCategory"
            //let notification = userInfo["notification"] as! [String: Any]
            content.title =  userInfo["title"] as! String
            content.body = userInfo["text"] as! String
            content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
            content.userInfo = userInfo

            //            //if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "logo", ofType: "png") {
            //            let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: userInfo["image"] as! String)
            //
            //            do {
            //                let attachment = try UNNotificationAttachment(identifier: "myNotificationCategory", url: url, options: nil)
            //                content.attachments = [attachment]
            //            } catch {
            //                print("The attachment was not loaded.")
            //            }
            //            //}

            let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "textNotification", content: content, trigger: trigger)

            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) {(error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Uh oh! We had an error: \(error)")
                }
            }
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
    }

    // [START connect_to_fcm]
    func connectToFcm() {
        // Won't connect since there is no token
        guard FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token() != nil else {
            return;
        }

        // Disconnect previous FCM connection if it exists.
        FIRMessaging.messaging().disconnect()

        FIRMessaging.messaging().connect { (error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("Unable to connect with FCM. \(error)")
            } else {
                print("Connected to FCM.")
            }
        }
    }
}

// [START ios_10_message_handling]
@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)
        //scheduleNotification(userInfo: userInfo)
        // Change this to your preferred presentation option
        completionHandler([.alert])
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        print(response.actionIdentifier)
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)
        //scheduleNotification(userInfo: userInfo)
        completionHandler()
    }
}
// END ios_10_message_handling
// START ios_10_data_message_handling
extension AppDelegate : FIRMessagingDelegate {
    // Receive data message on iOS 10 devices while app is in the foreground.
    func applicationReceivedRemoteMessage(_ remoteMessage: FIRMessagingRemoteMessage) {
        print(remoteMessage.appData)
        scheduleNotification(userInfo: remoteMessage.appData)
    }
}
// [END ios_10_data_message_handling]
```

And my extention file contains this:-

class NotificationViewController: UIViewController, UNNotificationContentExtension {

```
@IBOutlet var label: UILabel?

var contentHandler: ((UNNotificationContent) -> Void)?
var bestAttemptContent: UNMutableNotificationContent?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any required interface initialization here.
}

func didReceive(_ notification: UNNotification) {
    self.label?.text = notification.request.content.body
}
```

}

JSON i am sending Through fcm is:-

```
 {
  "to": "c0jlO4sWiog:APA91bGSlGYe27xA5DdyLcgm1xlSyxmWrfPOzNHnTv6Jp0QT0MnzqHoekSpnuNvppGDwQYB-jyV-gtxvYDdBjxsc_I1u1uvYqNHqXEB8ki-UnRNKqFJcwCSAljNOm2Ax0AuFFLy5qMq1",
  "priority" : "high",
   "notification" : {
  "title": "adfsas",
  "body" : "dasdfadf",
  "category" : "myNotificationCategory",
  "content_available": true,
  "mutable_content": 1
   },
   "data": {
    "text": "fadsfa",
    "title":"asfdafa",
    "image":"http://feelgrafix.com/data/images/images-1.jpg"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For category in fcm u need to give click_action: key in place of category.

```
{
  "to": "cVA176y69bk:APA91bFprDK2CeYG8W4P6Fu0bn7FrvlXqI-voZUrNv3MH-HLLl-toswFc1luwjASf5b1phk5fMuy1APd3QcIT9qzsPbiX_dTaxhoGx6y-h05aDxDdcmYiYEWu7e0vuvWeCc9uloZCp1e",
  "priority" : "high",
  "content_available": true,
  "mutable_content": true,

  "notification" : {
  "title": "dsaasf",
  "body" : "afaadfad",
  "click_action" : "myNotificationCategory"
   },
   "data": {
    "text": "adsfaf",
    "title":"asfads",
    "image":"http://feelgrafix.com/data/images/images-1.jpg"
   }
}
```